# How do i deal with an attribute error?

Tags: django, django-urls

I have these three functions,i have arranged them in such away that they

```
def show_order(request,id):
    order = Order.objects.get(pk=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        postdata = request.POST.copy()
        if postdata['submit'] == 'Remove':
            order.remove_from_order(request)
        if postdata['submit'] == 'Update':
            order.update_order(request)
        if postdata['submit'] == 'checkout':
            """once confirmed order, click checkout and redirect to checkout_form"""
            return HttpResponseRedirect(urlresolvers.reverse('checkout',kwargs={'id':order.id}))
    ....

def show_checkout(request,id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        resto = Restaurant.objects.get(pk=id)
        postdata = request.POST.copy()
        form = forms.CheckoutForm(request.POST,postdata)
        if form.is_valid():
            """create order after validating form"""
            order_created = create_order(request,resto)
            order_number = order_created.id
            if order_number:
                request.session['order_number'] = order_number
            if postdata['submit'] == 'place order':
                reciept_url = urlresolvers.reverse('checkout_reciept')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reciept_url)
    ......

def create_order(request,obj):
    """create new online_order containing each orderitem instance,save order and empty the order."""
    anon_user = User.objects.get(id=settings.ANONYMOUS_USER_ID)
    resto = Restaurant.objects.get(pk=obj.id)
    orders = Order()

    checkout_form = forms.CheckoutForm(request.POST,instance=orders)
    checkout = checkout_form.save(commit=False)

    checkout.created_by = anon_user
    checkout.modified_by = anon_user
    checkout.restaurant = resto
    checkout.status = Order.SUBMITTED
    checkout.save()

    if checkout.pk:
        """if the order save suceeded"""
        for ci in cart_items:
            """create order for each order_item"""
            ........
```

here are the urls

```
url(r'^your_order/(?P<id>\d+)/$',show_order,name="order_index"),
url(r'^checkout/(?P<id>\d+)/$',show_checkout,name="checkout"),
```

i get `AttributeError`, `'Order' object has no attribute 'get_order_items'` when i try and redirect from `show_order` to `show_checkout`

what in general i was trying to do is design urls for both views (`show_checkout`,`show_order`) but that is not working out.

The problem was, a conflict between variable `order=Order.objects.get(pk=id)`in `show_order` and a line `order.get_order_items(request)` in `show_checkout` which i did not include in the code above. so i changed variable `order` in `show_order` to `orders`. that fixed everything. Honest mistakes..

Comment: where did you get this `get_order_items`? I try to find it in your codes

Comment: its an exception django generated.. but ye it is not in the codes

Comment: Can you post also your full trace back of errors

Comment: If you can't find where the error is occuring with access to your code, how can you expect us to help you? Post the full stack trace and follow it to see exactly what is throwing the exception

Comment: @catherine thanks alot...its lesson learnt. looking at my traceback i was able to fix my problem...will edit my question.

Comment: If you have an answer, please enter it below and mark that as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was, a conflict between variable `order=Order.objects.get(pk=id)` in show_order and a line `order.get_order_items(request)` in show_checkout which i did not include in the code above. so i changed variable order in show_order to orders. that fixed everything. Honest mistake..